# Can't echo $_GET

Tags: php, get

I have a very very strange effect. ($_GET["var"] contains "testvalue")

My Code:

```
$_POST["var"] = $_GET["var"];
$test = $_GET["var"];

echo "<p>post: ".$_POST["var"]."</p>";
echo "<p>test: ".$test."</p>";
echo "<p>get: ".$_GET["var"]."</p>";
```

The output is:

```
post: testvalue

test: 

get:
```

Do you have any idea why the 2nd and 3rd output is not "testvalue"?

Comment: If you add 'echo $_GET["var"];' above the first line, what's the output?

Comment: Don't look at the HTML rendering, look at the actual output (HTML source).  Your pseudocode doesn't show your problem.

Comment: I doubt this really is the code you execute...

Comment: echoing $_GET["var"] also outputs nothing. When I look at the HTML Code with developer tools it is the same effect. (if that is what you mean @Devon)

Comment: run `var_dump($_REQUEST);` and paste result.

Comment: Are you using POST or GET to send the testvalue?

I don't see the point in having `$_POST["var"] = $_GET["var"];`

Comment: This is working as expected when I test it.

Comment: @mubin: $_REQUEST returns the crypted string which should be in $_GET. var_dump($_GET) is empty. which really don't understand.

Comment: then use $_REQUEST instead, because you're not sure about method that sending data to script.

Comment: Okay, with $_REQUEST it is working how i want it. I dont really understand it, because everywhere else in this script $_GET is used and its working. But it fixed my problem, so thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Your $_POST works, so it's filled.
Your get is moste likely not filled, turn te 2 around and it might work I think.
Try this:

```
$_GET["var"] = $_POST["var"];
$test = $_POST["var"];

echo "<p>post: ".$_POST["var"]."</p>";
echo "<p>test: ".$test."</p>";
echo "<p>get: ".$_GET["var"]."</p>";
```